# Ethernet led is not on, when cable is plugged in on both ends to online PCs

Tags: windows, linux, wired-networking

Even if network is missconfigured, leds should be on, right?

So here my network map:

```
modem_------cab1-------(eth0)_linux_(eth1)------cab2----_winxp
```

the led does NOT work ONLY when I connect eth1 with winxp, they seem to be the same cables.

It used to WORK before, when it was like this:

```
modem_------cab1-------(eth0)_winxp_(eth1)------cab2----_linux
```

Comment: Do you see both interfaces in /proc/net/dev? Are they both UP state?

Comment: What kind are the interfaces? gigabit ethernet? "fast" ethernet (100MB)?

Comment: I think beegeees was close, cable order matters...

Answer (score 2):

if you got a router/switch/hub between then then yes you should get Link_LED_ON
if your trying to connect them directly you probably need a differnt cable -> crossover-cable

Answer (score 0):

No.  Most cards have several LEDs. Some which indicate an established link, some which indicate data transmission.

If your cards have no link, e,g, due to a broken cable, or because you use a plain Ethernet (not a crosscable) between olders network interfaces without MDI/MDX then you will not get a link.

Your card could also be one with only a transmission LED. In which case establishing merely a link but not transmitting anything would not cause it to light up.

In your case I would start with:

1. Do things work as expected, just no LED. (In which case see above two reasons).
2. If it does not work, do a have a proper cable (cross cable)
3. Does my cable work with other hardware? (not only right type, but is it also unbroken).

...

Comment: 1. NO, xp says no connection, LED works, see edit; 2. used to work, see edit; 3. see 2;

Comment: OK, wokrs now...
I just exchanged cab1 with cab2 and it worked...